# How do I know all the exceptions that a method throws in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

For example I want to write a REST client. Instead of having a single catch statement for all the calls, I would like to know all the thrown messages and see if I can handle them.

It is really simple in Eclipse and Java. The problem is that for some of the methods, the signature and the doc doesn't tell me all the Exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# doesn't support 'Checked Exceptions' like Java has.

The only thing you can do, is rely on the documentation (MSDN, if the method in question is part of the .NET framework) ...

And, even if C# should have checked exceptions, then, you still cannot extract from the signature all exceptions that the method could throw.  It only mentions the exceptions that you have to catch, when calling the method.

Comment: Which is not always complete or accurate...But .net docs are still the best on msdn!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to catch all exceptions. You should only catch exceptions that you actually know  how to *handle*.

Comment: Yes so the question is how do I know all the exceptions thrown?

Comment: Ok... but it is often a very good idea to consult the docs and see what errors might be thrown, because more often than not you'd know how to handle quite a few that you didn't think of

Comment: The answer is that you don't know all the exceptions thrown, and you don't want to know them. You should only worry about the exceptions that you can actually _do_ something about. If you can't fix the problem, then what do you plan to do about it?

Comment: Nice theory.  Unfortunately, there are many situations where one will know how to correctly handle 99.44% of exceptions that might be thrown, but have no way of identifying them.  For example, one calls Spreadsheet.ReadFromFile(), which reads the file somehow; suppose it throws an ArgumentException, an AcmeFileReader.TroubleWithBlock37HeaderException, or some exception one has never heard of.  Most likely, the correct behavior will be to inform the user that the file couldn't be loaded, without preventing the user from using or continuing to use other files.

Comment: I can't exactly fault programmers who assume that for any non-specifically-handled exception they can put up an error message but let the program continue (abandoning the effort to load the file), since 99.44% of the time that will be the right course of action.  In many cases, a programmer will have to deal with exceptions thrown by code he has no control over, so it may not be possible to enumerate all possible exceptions that are best handled by simply abandoning efforts to load the file.

Comment: @supercat: I don't know where your statistics are from, but 99.44% of the time is not my experience. This is a case where I would put the try/catch in the button click handler and do no more than indicate to the user "sorry, I couldn't do that".

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear?  I was saying that 99.44% of the time the right course of action is to pop up a message saying "Couldn't read the file", effectively abandoning efforts to load it, which is what you say you'd do.

Comment: But I would do it at a high level, in the UI event handler, not around every method call.